# Python BeautifulSoup and class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new with scraping and  I am trying to undestart how its work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


link = r'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/sprzedam-komfortowy-dom-ID4div1'
r_off = requests.get(link)
off_page = bs(r_off.content, "html.parser")
parameters = off_page.find_all("div", {"class": "css-1d9dws4 egzohkh2"})
print(parameters)
```

When I use that code a get some results but I can't find that class using Inspect on website

Comment: well that means either the that there is some login system and without login you get a different hmtl template or something like that or you just need to look harder

Answer (score 0):

Truth is in your soup - So always take a look. CSS `classes` can be generated dynamically and differ from time to time, by entry point, ...

Good news, you do not even need a `class` you are free to find and select the content also by other information provided `attributes` for example the `role`:

```
off_page.select('div[role="region"]')
```

#### Example

Just iterate over the result and put it in a dict:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


link = r'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferta/sprzedam-komfortowy-dom-ID4div1'
r_off = requests.get(link)
off_page = bs(r_off.content, "html.parser")

dict([x.get_text().split(':') for x in off_page.select('div[role="region"]')])
```

#### Output

```
{'Powierzchnia działki': '300 m²',
 'Powierzchnia': '170 m²',
 'Rynek': 'wtórny',
 'Liczba pokoi': '5',
 'Rodzaj zabudowy': 'bliźniak',
 'Liczba pięter': '1 piętro',
 'Materiał budynku': 'pustak',
 'Dach': 'płaski',
 'Pokrycie dachu': 'papa',
 'Stan wykończenia': 'do zamieszkania',
 'Okna': 'plastikowe'}
```